# Can we save another dataframe in a dataframe column?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

I have multiple small dataframes. I want to create a single dataframe out of all these small dataframes. The schema for the combined dataframe we be like [key,value], where key will be the name of source dataframe and in value want to save to actual dataframe.

So the schema of combined dataframe be like;

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- actual-dataframe: binary (nullable = true)
```

I'm able to create such a dataframe, but not able to retrieve values at the time of read.

Code that I have so far:

```
case class AccountsData(empId: String, deptId: String, fName: String, lName: String)
case class PositionsData(positionId: String, date: String)

import sparkSession.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val accountdata = List(AccountsData("1", "100", "FN1", 
"LN1"),AccountsData("2", "100", "FN2", "LN2"))
val accountsDf = accountdata.toDF()

val positionsData = List(PositionsData("10011001", "01-Jan- 
 2022"),PositionsData("20012001", "02-Jan-2022"))
val positionsDf = positionsData.toDF()


implicit def single[A](implicit c: ClassTag[A]): Encoder[A] = 
Encoders.kryo[A](c)
implicit def tuple2[A1, A2](implicit e1: Encoder[A1],
                          e2: Encoder[A2]
                         ): Encoder[(A1, A2)] = Encoders.tuple[A1, A2](e1, e2)

val sequenceFileSchema = List("key", "actual-dataframe")
val combinedDf = List(("accounts-data", accountsDf), ("positions-data", positionsDf)).toDF(sequenceFileSchema:_*)


val acctRetainedDf1 = combinedDf.filter(col("key") === "accounts-data").select(col("actual- 
dataframe"))
```

I want to retrieve values from this dataframe --> acctRetainedDf1

Comment: hard to follow, what about an example?

Comment: I have a dataframe, accountDF, schema of this dataframe is (accountkey: String). I have another dataframe positionDF, schema of this dataframe is (positionId: String, date: Long). I want to have have a merged dataframe, which will have following data; (key --> accounts, value --> accountDf, key --> positions, value --> positionDF), just like a hashmap. The schema of this merged dataframe will be (key: String, value:Binary). Dataframe column 'value' can have dataframes of different schemas.

Comment: I am able to get the 'value' column using filter + select, like I have shared in the actual query, but not able to convert it into original dataframe. The dataframe that I am getting, contains binary data. I need to convert that data into the actual schema.

Comment: best to draw a schematic example.

Comment: val sequenceFileSchema = StructType(List(StructField("key", StringType, true),
    StructField("actual-dataframe", BinaryType, true)))
  val df1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List(Row("accounts-data", accountsDf))), sequenceFileSchema)
  val df2 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(List(Row("positions-data", positionsData))), sequenceFileSchema)

  val combinedDf = df1.unionByName(df2)

Comment: val acctRetainedDf1: Dataset[(String, AccountsData)] = combinedDf
    .filter(col("key") === "accounts-data")
    .map((row) => {
    (row.getAs[String]("accounts-data"), row.getAs[Array[Byte]]("actual-dataframe").asInstanceOf[AccountsData])
  }).toDF("k", "v").as[(String, AccountsData)]